# Perda de informação ao ordenar um datatable dentro de uma Modal com AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Boa Tarde.

Tenho uma lista ação que abre uma modal e exibe uma série de informações com paginação dentro de um datatable, e quero dar a opção do usuario ordenar essa informação, porem ao clicar no icone de order, independente de qual atributo eu uso pra ordenar, os dados somem, gostaria de pensar em uma solução que nao precisasse fazer uma nova consulta ao banco somente com os dados que já foram carregados. Segue códigos.

```
    $('#modalCandidatos').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#loader').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#candidatos').addClass('d-none');
    $('#vaga-vazia').addClass('d-none');

    var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var recipient = button.data('id-vaga');

    $('#lista_candidatos').empty();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/candidatos_vaga/'+recipient,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(data)
      {

        if(data.candidatos.length == 0){
          $('#loader').addClass('d-none');
          $('#vaga-vazia').removeClass('d-none');
        }
        else{
          $('#loader').addClass('d-none');
          $('#candidatos').removeClass('d-none');
          for (var i = 0; i < data.candidatos.length; i++) {

            var nome = '';

            if(data.candidatos[i].status == 1){
              nome = '<td>'+data.candidatos[i].nome+'<span class="ml-2 badge badge-secondary" index="'+data.candidatos[i].id+'">Novo</span></td>';
            }
            else{
              nome = '<td>'+data.candidatos[i].nome+'</td>';
            }

            $('#lista_candidatos').append(
            '<tr>'+
                nome+
                '<td>'+data.candidatos[i].cidade+'/'+data.candidatos[i].estado+'</td>'+
                '<td class="text-center">'+data.candidatos[i].curriculo+'%</td>'+
                '<td class="text-center">'+
                  '<a href="/candidatos/'+data.candidatos[i].id_candidato+'/'+data.candidatos[i].id+'" class="text-center alterar_candidato" style="text-decoration:underline" title="Ver currículo" target="_blank" index="'+data.candidatos[i].id+'">Ver currículo</a>'+
                '</td>'+
            '</tr>'
            );
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Codigo ajax que recebe a ação de exibir e popular a modal. Codigo abaaixo é da modal

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalCandidatos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Candidatos à vaga</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="loader">
          <div class="lds-default"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
          <p>Carregando...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="vaga-vazia" class="d-none p_5">
          <p class="text-muted">Nenhum currículo cadastrado para essa vaga.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="candidatos" class="d-none">
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered first">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Nome</th>
                          <th>Cidade</th>
                          <th>Currículo</th>
                          <th>Ações</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="lista_candidatos">
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ele atualiza a pagina em vez de somente ordenar os dados. Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

È o  modo que você está limpado a table com o

`$('#lista_candidatos').empty();`

coloca ele depois do success do ajax

Comment: Vou testar aqui, já te dou o retorno, Obrigado!

Comment: Nao funcionou : /. ai continua sumindo com os dados

Comment: pode ser o modo que você esteja limpado a table com o `$('#lista_candidatos').empty();` coloca ele depois do `success` do `ajax`

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, um colega de trabalho chegou na mesma conclusão hahaha. Obrigado. responde ae pra eu marcar como resposta.

Comment: que bom que deu certo kk. editada!